# jquery collapsible menu opens on scroll from mobile only

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

having an issue with a jquery function. I have a few resize events that collapses the navigation at certain widths. Works fine from desktop view but on the phone, the menu triggers open when I start to scroll down the page on first page load. Once I close it and scroll down the page again it's fine. Can't figure this out. Any help is much appreciated..

```
//---HIDE AND OPEN MENU ON BUTTON CLICK---//
$('#mobile_menu_btn').click(function () {
    $('nav ul').slideToggle('fast', function () {
        $(this).css('display') == 'none' ? $(this).removeClass('showNav').addClass('hideNav').removeAttr('style') : $(this).removeClass('hideNav').addClass('showNav').removeAttr('style');
    });
})

//---TRIGGER AUTOMATIC MENU BUTTON CLICK AT SPECIFIED PAGE WIDTH---//
window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
function resize() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 550) {
        jQuery(function () {
            jQuery('#mobile_menu_btn').click();
        });
        window.removeEventListener('resize', resize);
    }
}

//---TRIGGER AUTOMATIC MENU BUTTON CLICK AT SPECIFIED PAGE WIDTH ON PAGE LOAD ONLY ---//
if (window.innerWidth < 550) {
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('#mobile_menu_btn').click();
    });
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjensen/t7udk8ao/12/)

Comment: could you please share a codepen or jsfiddle link with proper setup (html, css, js) ?

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay. Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tjensen/t7udk8ao/12/